# Why are Ads not visible on my wordpress website?

Tags: ads, adsense

i included the generated add code provided by google adsense but the adds are not visible on my website. When i inspected i observed that where i included the add snippet on my page it occupy space on my webpage but not visible. Does it take time to approve the adds on your website when you use google adds for the first time?

Comment: You have AdBlock enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If your site is a wordpress.com based site, then AdSense ads are not allowed due to the terms and conditions of wordpress.com. Look in the wordpress.com terms and conditions under "advertising" for the details. If your site is not a wordpress.com site, then these are the possibilities:

1. Your account is not approved for a TLD (Top Level Domain like example.com) website. Another words, your site isn't a full AdSense account but instead is one for a host partner like YouTube, Blogger or AdMob. If this is the case, you'll need to apply for and be approved for an account upgrade.
2. You have an error in the way you implemented the adcode. Check the source code of your page and compare the adcode that shows there with what AdSense generated for you. If it isn't exactly the same, the ads may not display.
3. You've applied for a new AdSense account and are in the first step of approval, where you implement the adcode but haven't been fully approved to show ads. The process takes a few weeks.

If one of these options don't seem to apply, explain your situation and provide your URL for examination.